# How to share data from iOS Today Widget to Apple Watch app?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, today-extension

For my iOS app I have a Today extension and an Apple Watch app. In Today Widget I store data to user defaults, and in main app I'm accessing it using an app group. Everything works, but the only problem is using widget and watch app at the same time, without opening the host app: after adding data in the widget, the watch data is not updated and I'm not able to find a way to do this as long as shared UserDefaults are no longer supported in the watch since watchOS 2.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.